# How to build an ANTLR grammar with Gradle in a multi-platform project?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, antlr4, kotlin-multiplatform

So I have been struggling all afternoon with getting some Gradle build to work for a Kotlin multiplatform project that involves an ANTLR grammar. What I'm trying to do is to have a parser generated by ANTLR from a shared grammar for both a Kotlin (or Java if that doesn't work) and JavaScript target. Based on this I'd like to write some library around the parser that can be used from the JVM and JavaScript.

So I have set up a Kotlin multi-platform project because that seemed like a nice way of killing two birds with one stone (here is a repo https://github.com/derkork/project.txt). I created a source set `commonAntlr` where I placed the grammar file under `commonAntlr/antlr/project_txt.g4`. According to the documentation of the ANTLR plugin this is how stuff should be set up. I also apply the `antlr` plugin at the top (here is the `build.gradle.kts` - https://github.com/derkork/project.txt/blob/master/build.gradle.kts).

Now I run `gradle build` in the hopes that the ANTLR plugin will at least try to generate some nice Java code for me from the grammar using the default settings. Alas, it does not. The ANTLR plugin does not even get started, which is what I can tell from the output. The build later fails with some obscure JavaScript problem, but that looks unrelated and I'd like to skip over it for now.

Now my Gradle-foo isn't exactly strong (I have only used it in extremely simple projects, most of my experience is in Maven), and I have the distinct feeling I'm missing something here. However the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html) of the plugin just says

> To use the ANTLR plugin, include the following in your build script:
>
> plugins {
>       antlr 
>   }

Which I did. Since I get zero output, I have a feeling that I need to do a bit more for this to work. I have read a lot of the Gradle documentation up and down to find out how plugins work in general and I found that they add tasks to the build and also add some dependencies so that tasks are invoked when you try to build certain things. However I don't really understand how plugins work together with source sets and how you can tell Gradle "would you please run the `generateGrammarSource` task for this source set" (or if it even works like this).

So if some of the Gradle gods could enlighten me on this, this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I have met a similar issue: https://gitlab.com/pika-lab/tuprolog/2p-in-kotlin/tree/feature/parser

My solution -- which is still a work in progress -- consists in decomposing the problem.
I reasonable solution in my opinion is to create a Kotlin/JVM project (say `parser-jvm`) where to put the generated Java code + any JVM specific facility, and a Kotlin/JS project where to put the generated JS code + any JS specific facility (say `parser-js`). The next step is to create a Kotlin/MPP (say `parser-common`) project whose JVM implementation depends on `parser-jvm` and whose JS implementation depends on `parser-js`.

My approach is actually working for JVM while I'm experiencing some issues for JS, which are mostly caused by [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36259).

The main drawback of this approach is that some Gradle coding is required to setup ANTLR with Kotlin/JS. I already faced this problem in my [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/pika-lab/tuprolog/2p-in-kotlin/blob/feature/parser/parser-js/build.gradle.kts) and I'm quite satisfied with the result and the overall architecture of the project. However, I believe that my proposal is far less troublesome than configuring a Kotlin/MPP project to work with ANTLR.

Comment: This looks interesting, but man those build files are massive. The amount of stuff you need to do to make Gradle do what you want is mind-boggling. I already spent way more time on this than on the actual implementation and I'm seriously considering shell scripts at this point as this is probably easier to handle (and less code) than fighting the Gradle.